# What Language should I use for automated testing?

Tags: programming, multimeter, testing, spectrum-analyzer, power-meter

I'm the Lab Manager for a small company in the RF industry and I've recently been asked by our engineer to find a more "up-to-date" programming option for automating my bench testing/calibration procedures (sub-assembly testing and top level calibration).  I DID NOT write any of the current code that we have for testing and the person/people that did write it have not worked here for about two years.  We currently use Visual Basic express 2008 and Visual Studio 6.0.  I understand that these are extremely old and I am to the point where I can not even use my new computer because the old style software is not compatible with Windows 7.  I've tried upgrading to the newest version of Visual Studio and my old code is not even compatible with the newer versions.  I have little knowledge of programming but am very familiar with the equipment that I am using (I can basically troubleshoot and modify what I currently have). I'm looking for a good language to learn that will work best with using my equipment (DMM's, Power supplies, power meters, spectrum analyzer, etc..)  If you need more information to help me out I will try my best to answer any questions that you might have.  I'm extremely open to anything and am willing to take online training or whatever is necessary.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Do you at least have C libraries to communicate with the devices?

Comment: This is all going to depend on what kind of options each individual piece of hardware offers.

Comment: I'd recommend C#, it's what we use at my company, and it seems to work really well. Just my opinion, as any answer here might be.

Answer (score 3):

When I was asked to set this sort of environment up for the company I last worked for, I ending up choosing Python.  I was in the same sort of situation; the previous person who had done this several years previous had used VB 6.0, and I didn't want to have to run it out of a virtual XP box.

Although I had not used Python before, I chose to use it because it was scriptable. You don't have to go through edit/compile/link & package steps.  All you have to do is edit the source file (its plain text) and restart the program.

Python is completely free, but if you want to edit and run your Python program in an IDE (Integrated Development Environment, like Visual Studio), then there are several available; I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

A Python program [looks more like VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575403/pyusb-usb-barcode-scanner) than C -- for example, there are no squiggly braces { }.  Nesting is done by indentation, which seems a little strange at first, but then becomes second nature.

It runs on just about anything; PCs running Windows or Linux, or single board computers  like the Raspberry Pi.  Python is a mainstream language, [just below C# and PHP](http://www.sixfeetup.com/blog/why-we-choose-python) in popularity, and rising.  It's used extensively by major companies like Google and Disney.

Obviously, none of this measn anything unless you can communicate with your devices.  You didn't meniton what kind of interfaces they have, whether sereial, or USB, whatever.  There's libraries for just about everything: [PyUSB](http://walac.github.io/pyusb/) for USB access; [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) for RS232, etc. etc.  I use it in conjunction with a little board called the [Bus Pirate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_Pirate), which lets me control I²C and SPI busses.  Yep, there's libraries for those too.

Note: As you look around, you'll find there are two main versions of Python around, Python 2 and Python 3. "[Python 2.x is legacy, Python 3.x is the present and future of the language](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)".  Unfortunately though, Python 3 is not backwards compatible with Python 2.  Its better to go with Python 3, but make sure all of the libraries you need support it (some still don't, but that's becoming less and less of a problem).  As of this writing, the two actual versions are [Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.3](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: I would recommend Python as well, even if you had to use ctypes or Cython to access libraries for the devices/interfaces.

Comment: There are a number of instrument abstraction libraries for Python as well.  I'm actually part of https://github.com/LabPy where we are working on a new instrument control framework to supersede several existing frameworks under a unified banner.  It will support instrument control through PyVISA, which can access instruments over USB, serial, ethernet, and GPIB.

Answer (score 0):

More important than the language question is to understand how does the current system works. How does it communicates with the hardware modules? When this is OK, search for options to implement your brand new system.

For me, Python and C# seems reasonable choices but it all depends on what kind of communications you have. I personally like Delphi/Freepascal but this is me only.

Comment: Please add some more details like does it uses RS232, USB, Bluetooth, Ethernet, RS485 as the lower level of communications with your devices? Having that information at hand, does your hardware uses a specific communication protocol/commands in order to perform tasks while being remotely controlled by a, e.g., host PC? If so, do you have the documentation of this?

Comment: I communicate with my test devices via USB and RS-232.  My test bench equipment is all connected and communicate via GPIB.  In terms of documentation, I'm not sure what you are wanting.

Comment: Documentation means basically protocol description and message semantics. When you comunicate you send/receive bytes though whatever channel (USB, RS232, etc). The question was about how to give semantics to these bytes. This, in general, is written in some manual, tech doc, protocol description or whatever name you give.